# Should I "move" my chess and poker questions to the board and games site?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I believe that chess and poker questions would ultimately find a larger audience here on the board and card games (BCG) site, with the larger number of viewers more than making up for the "experts" that do (or don't) populate the other sites just because they are separate.

[Why do chess and poker have separate sites even though they are clearly "board and card games?"](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/why-do-chess-and-poker-have-separate-sites-even-though-they-are-clearly-board-a)

As you can see from the above Q and A, the management of the Stack Exchange disagrees with me. That's their prerogative.

What are MY prerogatives? Should I "vote with my feet," by asking future chess and poker questions on this site instead? More to the point, is there a way to move the existing questions I have on those sites to this one?

Apparently one reason why "Magic the Gathering" (MTG) was repatriated to this site, was because there were as many or more MTG questions here on BCG than on the "separate" MTG site, even though it was (at the time) actually larger than the chess and poker sites. Would moving one's questions here from the other sites help to tip the balance?

Comment: As one of the temp mods at Chess.SE, I think your use of scare quotes when referring to the "experts" there is both off-base and needlessly insulting. I'm impressed by the chutzpah required for *you* to pass judgment on e.g. Andrew Ng, Dag Oskar Madsen, Halvard, Andrew (mod), dfan and RemcoGerlich, just to name those who jump to mind as active examples of quite strong chess players who combine great communication skills with the effort and desire that's required to craft answers that will be useful and informative to players who are weaker or more novice than themselves.

Comment: @EdDean: "It's all relative." The above-mentioned are experts relative to the Chess site. But I was wondering if, in the absence of a Kasparov or at least a Seiwiran, whether we couldn't enlarge the pool of comparable people by joining the larger site. This was an opinion, and I stand by it. But I did not intend it to be a "judgment."

Answer (score 11):

There is no way to move existing questions.  I don't see any point in asking a moderator of the Chess or Poker sites to move chess or poker questions here.

Those sites exist and unless a decision is made by SE management to close one of them, questions won't be migrated.

You can ask new questions on whichever site makes the most sense to you.  We aren't the only sites facing these questions.  For example, a generic unix question could conceivable be on topic at many different SE sites.

Ask your questions where you feel comfortable doing so or where you think you'll get the best answers. You don't need to be exclusive either.  We'll let you date other SE sites :)

Answer (score 4):

You can choose to ask those questions here or in the poker and chess sites, that's your prerogative. But I doubt you can move already existing questions, you would have to flag your questions and ask a moderator to move them, but that would most likely be declined.

MTG wasn't repatriated because it had less MTG related questions that this site: the MTG proposal wasn't even allowed to start beta and was closed.